# Should i buy a twilio phone to send SMS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, sms, twilio-api

I am using this code for testing to send SMS everything work but i want to know if i have to buy a twilio phone to put it inside from: "" Because I want to send real SMS to my client

```
export const sendReservationConfirmationSMSTwilio = async ({
      firstName,
      reservationId,
      phone,
      date,
      hour,
      totalPersons,
    }) => {
      client.messages.create({
        body: `Bonjour, nouvelle réservation ${reservationId}! ${firstName} est joignable au ${phone}. Date: ${date} à ${hour}. Couverts: ${totalPersons} Commande: voir tableau de réservation`,
        from: '+15005550006',
        to: `+33${phone.slice(1)}`,
      }).then((res) => console.log(res)
    };
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to send SMS messages to your clients, you will need to either [buy a number from Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135247-How-to-Search-for-and-Buy-a-Twilio-Phone-Number-from-Console), [port in your existing phone number](https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/fr/porting), or use an [alphanumeric sender ID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS).

Otherwise, you seem like you are well on your way to successfully sending SMS messages.

Comment: I'm currently using alphnumeric senderID to send sms ex: from: 'TestTest'. I didn't receive any response. It work when I use this number +15005550006 test from: '+15005550006'

Comment: It looks, from your other answer, like you are getting an error message but not catching the error. If you chain `.catch(console.error)` after the `.then()` you will discover the issue. Also, the number you mention looks to be a test number, make sure you are using your production Account SID and Auth Token when you try to send with an alphanumeric sender ID.